# Code not giving the expected result in the for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the average of the spam confidence, but my for loop is not returning anything,

If I put the filename that is in the exercise, it doesn't return any value.

```
filename = input('Enter the name of the file: ')
count = 0
total = 0
fhandle = open(filename)
for line in fhandle:
    if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475'):
        tdts = line.find(':')
        num = line[tdts+1:-1]
        fnum = float(num)
        average = fnum / count
        total = total + fnum
        count = count + 1
        print(total)
average = total / count
print('Average spam confidence: ', average)
```

I expect the output of the average spam confidence.

Comment: Two, issues: `num = line[tdts+1:-1]`, this omits the last character in the line, `if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:0.8475')`, are you sure this is correct? This only fires when the line has the exact confidence `0.8475`. I think you just want to check if it has `X-DSPAM-Confidence`

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Let me quickly parse all the emails from the file and put them on some spam-email sender ... do you have consent of the ppl that are behind those email addresses to share them? ever heard of privacy protection?

Comment: That's a file from a site, that has been used as example from a course, there is nothing ilegal there. The course is Python for Everybody. It's a demonstration file.